# big data visualization social graph

Tags: graph, data-visualization, social-graph

I am working on a project involving social graph visualization and analisys.

There is a graph contain approximently ~2,000,000 nodes and ~1,000,000,000 edges.

We tried to use **Gephi** but we exceeded the limit of memory.

Can someone recommend a data visualization and analysis tool that can handle this amount of data?

Comment: Gephi doesn't seem to be the problem, your hardware does

Comment: Gephi showed message that said that graph I tryed to add exceed the memory limit and I need to Increase it from 450mb to 2700mb .. At first it didn't work but now I seems the it actually do work... So do you think that any time my graph will exceed the limit Gephi will let we increase the memory ?

Comment: I don't know how Gephi manages its memory, so I really can't answer that, sorry

Comment: From experience, gephi does very bad in terms of memory. Last time I tried to open a big graph in it, it asked me for 5GB of RAM just to open the file. Can't you make clusters of nodes in order to reduce the graph ?